# How to transform plane into clip space

Tags: linear-transformations

If I have a mapping that transforms 3D points from space A to space B

```
Point3 BfromA(Point3 p) {
  assert(p.z > 0); // Z coordinate is always positive
  return Point3(p.x / p.z, p.y / p.z, p.z);
}
```

I have planes in space A, defined by a normal vector and a signed distance from the origin (negative distance meaning that the origin lies on the side of the plane the normal points to).

How do I properly transform such planes into space B?

Answer (score 0):

Given the normal vector $\hat{u}=(A,B,C)$ and a distance $D$, the plane is a set of points $v=(x,y,z)$ such that $v\cdot\hat{u}=D$, which is a plane with equation $Ax+By+Cz=D$.

Given the mapping $(x,y,z)\mapsto(a,b,c)=(x/z,y/z,z)$,
and plane $Ax+By+Cz=D$.

Then using the inverse mapping $(a,b,c)\mapsto(x,y,z)=(ac,bc,c)$ , we can derive the plane as $Aac+Bbc+Cc=D$ or using the assumption that the $z=c$ is non-zero, $Aa+Bb-D/c=-C$ which is plane in axis of $(a,b,1/c)$.

It depends on you how you want to get the transformed plane.

Comment: so what would be the equation for the plane in terms of a B-space normalVector and a B-space distance?

Comment: It's basically not a plane thus there's no such quantity.

Comment: Are you sure it's not? I think a plane should remain a plane under this mapping...